# "I'm at home all of the day" vs. "I'm at home all the day"

Tags: prepositions, idiomatic-language

What's the difference or which one is more idiomatic, if any?

> - I'm at home all **of** the day.
> - I'm at home all the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your examples is idiomatic although both are perfectly understandable and would hardly raise an eyebrow in conversation.

The most common expression would be **I am at home all day**. (Equally, **all morning/afternoon**.)

Of your two, the former is more likely although you will hear the expression **all the day long**, often in a poetic or lyrical context.

Comment: So it's better to say "I am at home all day because of quarantine"?

Comment: @JudiciousAllure "*I'm stuck home **all day***" is perhaps more fitting considering the circumstances. N.B no article in front of "day" unlike in your version.

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: You can use the expression 'all the day', but not about the day that has not finished yet. This phrase bears a strong idiomatic meaning of 'all that day' in the modern usage and refers in practice to some day that was in the past. That is why the sentence * 'I am at home all the day.' can be percieved as ungrammatical in the modern usage.

Comment: A couple of centuries ago you'd [as likely as not include the article](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all+the+day+long%2Call+day+long&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Call%20the%20day%20long%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Call%20day%20long%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Call%20the%20day%20long%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Call%20day%20long%3B%2Cc0) in ***all the day long***, but next to no-one would do that today, "poetically" or otherwise.

Comment: It's more common (at least in British English) to just say "I'm home all day", without bothering with the "at" -- although with "stuck" I think it would be used: "I'm stuck at home all day".

Comment: @kngram: We still include the article in [***all the livelong day***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all+the+livelong+day&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Call%20the%20livelong%20day%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Call%20the%20livelong%20day%3B%2Cc0), but that's effectively a "frozen form", not reflective of  more general usage today.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica: It seems that it looks as *the whole day* in the modern usage. Thanks.

Comment: @kngram: I don't know what gave you that impression! Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=been+here+the+whole+day%2Cbeen+here+all+day&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeen%20here%20the%20whole%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeen%20here%20all%20day%3B%2Cc0), *I've been here **the whole day*** is virtually unknown by comparison with *I've been here **all day***. Whether to include ***of*** (if you ***are*** going to include an article) is trivial compared to the main issue, which is that you probably ***don't*** want the article.

Comment: ) I compare *all the livelong day* with *the whole day*.https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all+the+livelong+day%2Cthe+whole+day&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Call%20the%20livelong%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20whole%20day%3B%2Cc0